# I am Trying to Install MacOS on VMware But during half installation a block icon appears and nothing to work

Tags: macos, vmware

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com)

during loading of macOS when loading half complete then this icon is appear

Comment: your picture's link is not correct, try to correct it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. You may get a better response on one of the other Stack Exchange sites. Note also that, AFAIK it is against the terms of the Apple licence agreement to install macOS on anything other than Apple hardware.